# Can Chrome dev tools show all dependencies for a CSS file throughout an entire site?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm wanting to eliminate a specific CSS file and move the styles that are being referenced to page-specific files. Because of how large the CSS file is, I am not sure of every dependency throughout the entire site. Is there any way to see all of the styles being referenced for a specific CSS file throughout the entire site, not just on the page loaded? Does Chrome Dev Tools, or any other tool, support this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There’s extensions for this kind of stuff – although you might have to “visit” all relevant pages. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/unusedcss/dokggbghedajooenkgjbamikfgnngeik

Comment: Please try to break down your question further with some clear specific details and perhaps some code examples.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe! I'm building on that extension to display the data I need with an updated UI.